# HTC Arrive Speaks incoming callers names during ringtone

Tags: 7.8

I just upgraded my HTC Arrive to WP 7.8 and now every time I receive a call it rings for a second or two then speaks the contact name aloud. I can't seem to find a setting to toggle this off. I don't necessarily want my contacts names read aloud.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the following setting may be turned on:

- Settings
- ease of access
- Speech for phone accessibility

Make sure it is set to off.